# Javascript - How to create regex similar to html pattern attribute

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using `pattern` attribute of html but it's failing in for some reason so I'm thinking on how to create `regex` for `javascript`.

Highlighted part of the image is the format that I'm validating using this regular expression `pattern` attribute `pattern="[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{7}"`. I still can't manage to build this using javascript.

Any answers/reference/solution is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Show JS code how and when you validate it.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Try my updated answer and its fiddles :)

Comment: In what way does it fail when you use `pattern`?

Comment: I'll post my code

Answer (score 2):

Your `RegExp` is correct but use `^` in first and `$` in last of it. then add `required attribute` like this:

```
 <form>
   <input type="text" name="formField" pattern="^[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{7}$" required />
   <input type='submit'/>
 </form>
```

[Try this online](http://jsfiddle.net/cayv1g7h/)

---

And if you want to use `javascript`:

`HTML`:

```
 <form>
   <input type="text" name="formField" />
   <input type="button" value='submit'/><input style='display: none' type='submit'/>
 </form>
```

`javascript`:

```
document.querySelector('[type="button"]').onclick=function(){
   if(/^[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{7}$/.test(document.querySelector('[name="formField"]').value)==false) return alert("Please check input value and try again!");
   this.nextSibling.click()
};
```

[Try it online](http://jsfiddle.net/cayv1g7h/6/)

---

And, if you have not `form`, you can try this simple way:

`HTML`:

```
<input type="text" name="formField" />
<input type="button" value='Add'/>
```

`javascript`:

```
document.querySelector('[type="button"]').addEventListener("click", function(){//or onclick = ...
   if(/^[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{7}$/.test(document.querySelector('[name="formField"]').value)==false) return alert("Please check input value and try again!");
   alert("Is OK!!");
});
```

[Try it too](http://jsfiddle.net/cayv1g7h/9/)

---

Try this for check manually typing:

```js
document.querySelector('[name="formField"]').addEventListener("keyup", function(ev){
       if(/^[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{7}$/.test(document.querySelector('[name="formField"]').value)==false) return this.style.backgroundColor="#f88";
       this.style.backgroundColor="#0f0";
    });
```

```html
<input type="text" name="formField" placeholder='Type here 4 test!'/>
```

Comment: works fine if i copy paste a valid format, but manually typing still returning false.

Comment: Have you tested my fiddles? all of them works correctly. Which part of my code do you use? is possible to put simple code (as fiddle in a comment) that you are using it and has this problem?

**I've added another part to my response for check manually typing.**

Answer (score 1):

Same pattern code will work in JS

```
var pattern = /[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{7}/
var qry = 'ASDF4567543';
if(qry.match(pattern)) {
    alert('valid');
}
else{
    alert('invalid');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex will work fine in JS. You just need to add start (`^`) and end (`$`) of string anchors to it, otherwise it will also match strings that are longer than 11 characters.

```js
let container='QWSA1231231';
console.log(/^[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{7}$/.test(container));
container='QWSA123121';
console.log(/^[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{7}$/.test(container));
container='QWSA12312312';
console.log(/^[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{7}$/.test(container));
```